# Polymer bind data through javascript string?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, polymer

I was wondering how to do the following:

```
<polymer-element name="x-foo" attributes="foo">
  <template>
    <div id="content"></div>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('x-foo', {
      foo: true,
      ready: function() {
        this.$.content.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<x-bar foo="'+this.foo+'"></x-bar>');
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

So that the `this.foo` is data binded and changes to the `foo` attribute will be affected if `x-foo` was implemented like so `<x-foo foo="{{foo}}"></x-foo>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not. If you're not using `foo={{foo}}`, than you're not using the data-binding system. The literal result of calling `insertAdjacentHTML` is:

```
<div id="content">
  <x-bar foo="true" id="xbar"></x-bar>
</div>
```

Which is static markup. Any future changes `this.foo` won't propagate to `x-bar` unless you manually update it:

```
fooChanged: function() {
  this.$.content.firstElementChild.foo = this.foo;
},
update: function() {
  this.foo = Math.random();
}
```

But this raises another inconvenience. Generally, one could use automatic node finding to reference `x-bar.foo` (`this.$.xbar`). Instead, one has to use DOM traversal (`this.$.content.firstElementChild`) because the element is added late, after Polymer has done its setup.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to dynamically insert a polymer-element after I get some data from an ajax request.